# Add new Channel ID access to multiple member groups via SQL Query

Tags: members, channel, query, sql, query-module

I have created a new channel (in this case ID#32) on an existing EE site install, and I need to assign it to 270 existing member groups.

Rather than clicking into every single member group and manually adding the the new channel under the '**Allowed Channels**' list, I was thinking it would be easier to write an SQL Query to the '**exp_channel_member_groups**' table so all **group_id**'s (that do not have a row stating the new/required **channel_id #32** number to have a row created etc, so you would have (for example) **group_id 01 channel_id 32** on so on.

Can anyone advise on the correct EE/SQL scripting I would need in order to get this to happen?

Many thanks in advance for any help on this :-)

Comment: I would think your client has a serious issue with CMS organization if you have to consider resorting to raw SQL queries to solve this. I might have something for you tomorrow, but suggest to your client some future refactoring. That sounds rough. Also, if I do throw something out there you can try, **please** have a throw-away dev server to test it on first.

Comment: Hi jrothafer, many thanks for the feedback on this, much appreciated. To be honest it's a site I have recently inhereted so the framework/infrastructure was already developed and in place, however there are numerous tasks I would have done differenty and will suggest to re-develop over time. Many thanks in advance for SQL solution when ready and yes everything is full tested at local/staging servers before live implementation, so all covered from that aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a SQL Utility like [Sequel Pro](https://sequelpro.com/) and a code editor it is pretty easy to do.

First you need to get a list of the groups that don't have the channel_id set.

Using the SQL Query tab of your utility enter a command like this (replace "7" with the channel_id of the one you've added):

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM exp_channel_member_groups WHERE channel_id <> 7;
```

This will give you a list of **group_id**'s in the output area of the Query window.

Select the list of **group_id**'s and copy them.

Now create a bit of SQL in a code editor (if it is any good you can paste in the list of group_ids and build the VALUES rows in one hit) to get some code that looks a bit like this:

```
INSERT INTO `exp_channel_member_groups` (`group_id`, `channel_id`)
VALUES
    (Your_group_id, channel_id_from_list_1),
    (Your_group_id, channel_id_from_list_2),
    (Your_group_id, channel_id_from_list_3),
    .... etc ... 
    (Your_group_id, channel_id_from_list_last);
```

Run that in your SQL utility query area and you'll get the updated data into the table.

HTH

Comment: Hi jcogs, the above solution worked a treat ans succesfully updated every member group with the required new channel ID number! I've made a full template of all the member group numbers hard coded into the SQL script provided above and all I need to do in the future is replace the existing channel ID in the script with a new one as required. Many thanks once again, this is an excellent solution! :-)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it worked - good news! :)